# Android Emulator clock not updating

Tags: android, time, android-emulator

I created an Emulator using Android Virtual Device Manager and, although I can run my app and use the emulator as a normal device, the clock never gets updated.

I did try to set an Alarm (using the native Android app "Clock") and after turning the alarm on I get the Toast saying that X time is left till my alarm rings, but it never does ring, neither the time on top bar updates (next to battery icon).

Where can I start/enable the Emulator clock?

Comment: `neither the time on top bar updates.` What do you mean?

Comment: For testing most applications it is best to use real devoces. I assume it is possible to start the clock somehow, but I don't know